# Firebase addChildEventListener giving loops

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an issue with Firebase addChildEventListener. Here is my code

```
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference().child("data");

        reference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Log.v("NOTIFICATION", "==" + dataSnapshot.getKey());
                Log.v("NOTIFICATION1", "==" + dataSnapshot.child("switch").getValue());


            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        });

        return true;
    }
});
```

The reference "data" data have 15 childs. When I change a data inside the 1st child i get the log **NOTIFICATION** as the key name of the first child for 15 times and **NOFTICATION1** as the changed switch data also for 15 times. Why do I get like this? Is this the default behaviour **addChildEventListener**. Is there any alternative method?? I need to get the datachange whenever I change data inside any of the 15 childs.

Comment: yes it is the default behavior

Comment: can you show us your structure

Comment: @Ali A main node "data" and it have 15 child and each of them have 5 child.

Comment: The behavior depends on where in the JSON you add this listener. Can you edit your question to show the JSON at `data` in your database (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen In this case, the listener is set on `data` node, as I see in OP's code. Where was I wrong? Thanks!

Comment: The `onChildChanged` event is fired for each child that is changed under the location where you attach the listener. If a child is not changed, there will be no `onChildChanged` call for that child. If OP sees it fire for each child on each change, it seems likely to me that the listener is attached to the wrong location.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Oh yes, you're right! I understand now your assumption. I have deleted my answer and I'll wait for OP's comment. Thanks again!

Comment: There was a good comment from Sayanh in that answer: "the 15 nodes have 5 child each. So i want to get a specific node from these 5 nodes whenever it changes from anyone of the 15 main nodes". Firebase child listeners alert you to changes on the child nodes of the location where you attach the listener. Firebase does not pass any information of what precisely changed in child nodes. If you need that, you should consider a data structure where the child nodes that you listen to correspond to what you want to get passed into `onChildChanged`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen mu need is to implement a notification on data change. So i got the problem that around 15 notifications are getting called with same data on a single node change. Finally i managed it with a Boolean constant it changes its status after the 1st notification is called. In my app there no condition that one more node changes in simultaneously.  So i imlement this method.its working fine now

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for your help